# Send Bulk Mail Using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Need to send mail for 4 to 5 emails one after another so used for loop and I'm trying to trigger email using PHPMAILER. However only for first email address mail is sent and for remaining its showing error.

**NOTE: *EVEN TRIED $mail->clearAddresses()***

**Below is my mail code**

```
      <?php
      require 'Send_Mail.php';
      $var = array("b2.pradeepan@gmail.com","pradeepan.7899@gmail.com","pan6831@gmail.com");

      for($i=0;$i<$var;$i++)
      {
       $to = $var[$i];
       $subject = "Bulk Mail";
       $body = "dummy loop";
       $op = Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body);
      }
    ?>
```

**Below is my PHPMAILER CODE**

```
        function Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body)
        {
         require 'class.phpmailer.php';
         $from = "XYZ@gmail.com";
         $mail = new PHPMailer();
         $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
         $mail->IsSMTP(true); // SMTP
         $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  // SMTP authentication
         $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
         $mail->Host       = "tls://smtp.gmail.com"; // Amazon SES server, note "tls://" protocol tls://email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
         $mail->Port       = 465;                    // set the SMTP port
         $mail->Username   = "XYZ@gmail.com";  // SES SMTP  username
         $mail->Password   = "XYZ";  // SES SMTP password
         $mail->SetFrom($from, 'XYZ@gmail.com');
         $mail->AddReplyTo($from,'XYZ@gmail.com');
         $mail->Subject = $subject;
         $mail->MsgHTML($body);
         $mail->clearAllRecipients();
         $address = $to;
         $mail->AddAddress($address, $to);
         if(!$mail->send()) {
            $mail->clearAddresses();
            return false;    
         }
         else
        {
          $mail->clearAddresses();
          return true;
        }
     }
```

**what is error in my code..??**

Comment: I hope that password isn't the actual password for your email..

Comment: Enable debugging to get the error I guess; https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging

Comment: "for remaining its showing error" - I think you forgot to share the exact error message...

Comment: @IsThisJavascript it is. Try logging in, you won't see a message stating that the password is wrong :(

Comment: Disappointing. I hope you change that password right now Yanduri...

Comment: Rather than point out the errors, it would be quicker to start again with the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer, and upgrade to the latest version since you're using an old one.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript...it is a dummy emailid whihc i was using for testing...Thanks for Notifying me.....and NicoHaase...I dont know if u tried to login or not...Have some manners of notifying instead of trying to login,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
 for($i=0;$i<$var;$i++)
```

as it is a endless loop to

```
for($i=0;$i<count($var);$i++)
```

or do a foreach

```
foreach($var as $to)
```

Comment: @FatFreddy...implemented those changes after I noticed the loop...thank you